# Why don't my items show up?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Can anybody tell me how to solve this please?
The items' icons don't show:

[image: Ingame_screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're unable to connect to the item server. This occasionally happens and is completely normal. Wait a few hours and it should be back.